# Apache svn - which file states are ready to commit?

Tags: svn

Apache svn - which states of files are ready to commit, except

```
A (scheduled for addition)
D (scheduled for deletion)
M (modified)
```

?

I do not find the list of commitable states in [doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check status help page: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html

I think also ready for commit is:

'R' Item has been replaced in your working copy